# What is a prevRowCountState in mui-data-grid?

Tags: material-ui

[Server pagination](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/pagination/#server-side-pagination), I understand the logic but can't figure out how does the grid know the value of `prevRowCountState`. Is it a undocumented thing, prefix a const/property with `prev` then the grid knows it's for the previous value?

```
const [rowCountState, setRowCountState] = React.useState(rowCount);
React.useEffect(() => {
  setRowCountState((prevRowCountState) =>
    rowCount !== undefined ? rowCount : prevRowCountState,
  );
}, [rowCount, setRowCountState]);

<DataGrid rowCount={rowCountState} />;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set<Something>` is action of `setState` method for `Something`. When supplying an argument in a form of function such as `set<Something>((whatever)=> {...});`, **whatever** is the previous state of **something**.

References:

- [React's State](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-setstate/), starting "To fix it, use a second form of setState()..."
- [Geek to Geek, example 4](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-setstate/),